# How do ROM makers get the newer proprietary blobs?

Tags: updates, custom-roms, rom, device-firmware

I would like to have a more up-to-date Android on my ancient device, that currently runs 4.1 (Qualcomm MSM8960). Have already applied all the patches to refresh the kernel with the features needed for newer Android to run, and confirmed that the new kernel is alive and is able to run in LineageOS 18.1. The new system errors out on getting up the periphery (WLAN, GSM, GPS etc), since the newer drivers require the proprietary blobs to exist. Surprisingly, stock 4.1 ROM appears to not requiring/having around the proprietary blobs for the periphery.

I have already seen the occurrences of upgrading devices of this chipset to the newer Android, but no answer was given to me on the origin of the required blobs.

So I wonder how can they get these newer blobs?

Comment: Proprietary blobs are always provided by the OEM of the device. ROM developers only extract them from a physical device running stock ROM and ship them with their custom ROM.